# If statement errors, Java

Tags: java, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Calculator!");
        System.out.println("Enter the first operand:");
        double firstOperand = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the second operand:");
        double secondOperand = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Operations are:");
        System.out.println("ADD or  + for addition");
        System.out.println("SUBTRACT or - for subraction");
        System.out.println("MULTIPLY or * for multiplication");
        System.out.println("DIVIDE or / for division");
        System.out.println("Enter your selection:");
        String selection = scan.next();
        double ADD = (firstOperand + secondOperand);
        double SUBTRACT = (firstOperand - secondOperand);
        double MULTIPLY = (firstOperand * secondOperand);
        double DIVIDE = (firstOperand / secondOperand);

        if (selection == ADD) {
            System.out.println("The product is:" + ADD);
        }
        if (selection == SUBTRACT) {
            System.out.println("The product is:" + SUBTRACT);
        }
        if (selection == MULTIPLY) {
            System.out.println("The product is:" + MULTIPLY);
        }
        if (selection == DIVIDE) {
            System.out.println("The product is:" + DIVIDE);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting for each of my if statements.

```
error: incomparable types: String and double
        if (selection == ADD)
```

I'm attempting to create a simple calculator and I do not understand what the error is trying to convey. I also want to assign two variables to one definition but I do not know how to go about it, especially with the `+`, `-` signs. Is it even possible to assign the `+` sign as a variable? For example I want `+` to equal the same thing as when I write `ADD`?

Comment: the error means you are comparing a `double` (number) with a `String` (text) using an identity comparison operator `==`, which simply makes no sense - do you know the difference between those data types and how to convert one into the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were comparing string to double. You need to compare string to string.
Here try this:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Assignment3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Calculator!");
    System.out.println("Enter the first operand:");
    double firstOperand = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the second operand:");
    double secondOperand = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Operations are:");
    System.out.println("ADD or  + for addition");
    System.out.println("SUBTRACT or - for subraction");
    System.out.println("MULTIPLY or * for multiplication");
    System.out.println("DIVIDE or / for division");
    System.out.println("Enter your selection:");
    String selection = scan.next();
    double ADD = (firstOperand + secondOperand);
    double SUBTRACT = (firstOperand - secondOperand);
    double MULTIPLY = (firstOperand * secondOperand);
    double DIVIDE = (firstOperand / secondOperand);

    if (selection.equals("+")) {
        System.out.println("The product is:" + ADD);
    }
    else if (selection.equals("-")) {
        System.out.println("The product is:" + SUBTRACT);
    }
    else if (selection.equals("*")) {
        System.out.println("The product is:" + MULTIPLY);
    }
    else if (selection.equals("/")) {
        System.out.println("The product is:" + DIVIDE);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As we can see from the error message, causes of different data types. You can use [`Double.parseDouble()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) to convert a String to a double.

```
...
if (Double.parseDouble(selection) == ADD)
...
```

P/S: you should change the tag from JavaScript to Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by changing the declaration of the variable

```
Double selection = new Double(scan.next());
```